Does corals need powerheads/wavemakers?
Does corals need powerheads/wavemakers? Or are they merely recommended as they create a cool affect within the aquarium.

are you asking if you need filtration,a powerhead is a part of your filter system.

@trondhansen I have a filter. Aren't powerheads/wavemakers a seperate thing from a standard water filter?
